# is it possible to mix react jsx with non jsx components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So the question I have right now is if I have a parent component that is JSX but I have the need to include an html tag such as `<i class="fa fa-window-maximize" aria-hidden="true"></i>` which I believe is not supported by react JSX(correct me if I am wrong) could I mix the jsx and non jsx components some how? I personally prefer JSX and haven't done any work without it really so I wouldn't want to stray away from this unless I have to.

```
<Parent>
   <Child>
      Mix non jsx code in here??
   </Child>
</Parent>
```

Comment: JSX can handle html tags. But in your example you have have to change `class` to `className`.

Comment: oh haha I can't believe I didn't see that I thought it just couldn't handle the italic tag. That fixes my issue thanks. Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You can mix JSX and non-JSX (HTML!) how you want! For example:

```
<div>
    <MyComponent>
        <input type="button>
    </MyComponent>
</div>
```

If you want to style an element you must use `className` instead of `class`. So your i tag must look like this

```
<i className="fa fa-window-maximize" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. How can I mix JSX with React.createElement() function?

Answer (score 1):

Have in mind that these "non-JSX" HTML elements are actually JSX elements too, have a look at [JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

```
<div className="sidebar" />
```

Compiles to:

```
React.createElement(
  'div',
  {className: 'sidebar'},
  null
)
```

To include classes in these components you need to use `className` instead of `class`, like this:

```
<i className="fa fa-window-maximize" aria-hidden="true" />
```

And yes, you can also mix them with your custom React components:

```
<MyComponent>
  <i className="fa fa-window-maximize" aria-hidden="true" />
</MyComponent>
```